# how to append string to <a href=" with jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I've the  elements as follows,

```
<div id="pager">
<a href="/somepath/1">First</a>
<a href="/somepath/1">Previous</a>
<a class="" href="/somepath/1">1</a>
<a class="Current" href="/somepath/2">2</a>
<a class="" href="/somepath/3">3</a>
<a href="/somepath/3">Next</a>
<a href="/somepath/20">Last</a>
</div>
```

and I want it to be changed as follows within browser.

```
<div id="pager">
<a href="/somepath/1?a=text">First</a>
<a href="/somepath/1?a=text">Previous</a>
<a class="" href="/somepath/1?a=text">1</a>
<a class="Current" href="/somepath/2?a=text">2</a>
<a class="" href="/somepath/3?a=text">3</a>
<a href="/somepath/3?a=text">Next</a>
<a href="/somepath/20?a=text">Last</a>
</div>
```

So that I can use the "a" data values to next page.
Can any one give me the code, which does the appends inside

> `div id="pager"` -> `<a>` -> `href="`

and i wants to remove the added text with another onChange event.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since jquery is tagged :

```
$('#pager a').each(function(){
     this.href += '?a=text';
})
```

Vanilla JS would look like this :

```
var a = document.getElementById('pager').getElementsByTagName('a'),
    length = a.length;

for(var i=0; i< length; i++){
    a[i].href += '?a=text';
}
```

Comment: @Bondye What is wrong with `.each` function? *"+1 Finally one without that .each() function... People don't understand .each().."*. The answer where you posted this comment, what do you think happen behind the code? Alsoo, `.each()` is faster : http://jsperf.com/each-vs-function

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Personally, I prefer to use `.attr()` with a function instead of `.each()` because I find it more readable. But I  certainly can't argue with performance testing. (I wonder if some optimization in jQuery could fix that?)

Comment: @Blazemonger Well that's a personnal preference since i prefer using `.each()`, So we cant arg on that :) @Bondye It is not looping twice, it is actually the same result as using a function (like Blaze's answer). Here the revelant part in jquery code : `for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
     fn( elems[i], key, raw ? value : value.call( elems[i], i, fn( elems[i], key ) ) );
    }. The only adding to the `.each` way is an additionnal function call (wich is why each is faster). I think your comment is more revelant for function like `.addClass()` wich is useless to loop through elements & call it after

Comment: @Blazemonger on a side note, the vanilla js is the slowest one. Any idea why (i probably did something wrong in the code)?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Probably something to do with [this (source code)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L566)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, how to remove the added text "?a=text" with the another onChange event?

Comment: @Vicky you can try `this.href = this.href.replace('?a=text', '');`

Answer (score 15):

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like many jQuery functions, can take a function argument that modifies the existing value:

```
$('#pager a').attr('href',function(i,str) {
   return str + '?a=text';
});
```

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks and I'll accept Karl-André Gagnon's answer. You have wow ans and how to remove the added text "?a=text" with the another onChange event?

Comment: "return str.split('?')[0];" should do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#pager a').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?a=text');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `attr property`. Example :-

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#pager").find("a").each(function(){
var $this=$(this);
$this.attr("href",$this.attr("href")+"?a=text");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method

```
$('a').attr('href', '/somepath/1?a=text');
```

And if you want to change the `href` of a specific `<a>` give that '' a unique id and than change its `href` as follows

```
$('#link').attr('href', '/somepath/1?a=text');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
$('#pager a').each(function(){
    this.href += '?a=text'
})
```